# FirebaseException: Use setDomainUriPrefix() instead, setDynamicLinkDomain() is only applicable for *.page.link and *.app.goo.gl domains

Tags: c#, android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm integrating firebase dynamic link 6.0.0 unity sdk downloaded from firebase official site. I am following the [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/unity/create) as it is to create long and short dynamic link. After creating long dynamic link with following C# code

```
var components = new DynamicLinkComponents(
    new Uri(BaseLink), DynamicPageLink) {
        IOSParameters = new IOSParameters(IOS_PACKAGE_NAME),
        AndroidParameters = new AndroidParameters(
        ANDROID_PACKAGE_NAME)
};
```

If I save long dynamic link into string for further processing `DynamicLinkURL = components.LongDynamicLink.ToString();` **Adb logs** shows same following error when I try to create short dynamic link.

> 05-13 14:18:59.177 14114 14140 E Unity   : FirebaseException: Use
>   setDomainUriPrefix() instead, setDynamicLinkDomain() is only
>   applicable for *.page.link and *.app.goo.gl domains. 05-13
>   14:18:59.177 14114 14140 E Unity   :   at
>   Firebase.DynamicLinks.ShortDynamicLink.ConvertFromInternal
>   (Firebase.DynamicLinks.GeneratedDynamicLinkInternal
>   generatedDynamicLink) [0x0001c] in
>   <09919938d588496b93526471cfc06f1e>:0 05-13 14:18:59.177 14114 14140 E
>   Unity   :   at
>   Firebase.DynamicLinks.DynamicLinkComponents.get_LongDynamicLink ()
>   [0x0000b] in <09919938d588496b93526471cfc06f1e>:0 05-13 14:18:59.177
>   14114 14140 E Unity   :   at
>   DynamicLinkHandler.CreateAndDisplayShortLinkAsync
>   (Firebase.DynamicLinks.DynamicLinkOptions options) [0x00000] in
>   <3fb360e7f75148dea3d18febec1704a9>:0 05-13 14:18:59.177 14114 14140 E
>   Unity   :   at DynamicLinkHandler.CreateAndDisplayShortLinkAsync ()
>   [0x00005] in <3fb360e7f75148dea3d18febec1704a9>:0 05-13 14:18:59.177
>   14114 14140 E Unity   :   at
>   DynamicLinkHandler+<>c.b__12_0 () [0x0005c] in
>   <3fb360e7f75148dea3d18febec1704a9>:0 05-13 14:18:59.177 14114 14140 E
>   Unity   :   at DynamicLinkHandler.CheckFirebaseDependencies
>   (System.Action OnDependencyResolved) [0x0000d] in
>   <3fb360e7f75148dea3d18febec1704a9>:0 05-13 14:18:59.177 14114 14140 E
>   Unity   :   at DynamicLinkHandler.Initialize (System.Action`1[T]
>   COnReferalRew 05-13 14:19:01.635 14114 14153 E Unity   :
>   java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Host unreachable

Code that I'm writing to generate short dynamic link is following.

```
public static Task<ShortDynamicLink> CreateAndDisplayUnguessableShortLinkAsync() {
        return CreateAndDisplayShortLinkAsync(new DynamicLinkOptions {
            PathLength = DynamicLinkPathLength.Unguessable
        });
    }

    private static Task<ShortDynamicLink> CreateAndDisplayShortLinkAsync(DynamicLinkOptions options) {

        return DynamicLinks.GetShortLinkAsync(components.LongDynamicLink)
          .ContinueWith<ShortDynamicLink>((task) => {
              if (task.IsCanceled) {
                  Debug.Log("Short link creation canceled");
              } else if (task.IsFaulted) {
                  Debug.Log(String.Format("Short link creation failed {0}", task.Exception.ToString()));
              } else {
                  ShortDynamicLink link = task.Result;
                  Debug.Log(String.Format("Generated short link {0}", link.Url));
                  var warnings = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>(link.Warnings);
                  if (warnings.Count > 0) {
                      Debug.Log("Warnings:");
                      foreach (var warning in warnings) {
                          Debug.Log("  " + warning);
                      }
                  }
              }
              return task.Result;
          });
    }
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Did you solve this issue @Farhan ul haq?